# Html position fixed bugs screen to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a responsive website where mobile devices get a menu button to see the menu. When this button is pressed it's possible to scroll, so I fixed that using `overflow: hidden;` and `position: fixed;`

For some reason the site "jumps" to the right and I can't scroll back. This is the source code:

```
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
            </div>
                <div class="menuToggle">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            <div id="nav">
                <div class="aanmelden">
                    <a href="">Aanmelden</a>
                </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Download app</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Over GYM2Go</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </body>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    menuToggle();
});

var down = false;

function menuToggle() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.menuToggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
        $('#nav').toggleClass('active');
        $('body').toggleClass('active');

        if (down) {
            $('.lastItem').remove();
            down = false;
        } else {
            $("ul").append('<li class="lastItem"><a href="">Aanmelden</a></li>');
            down = true;
        }
    });

    $('#nav > ul > li').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#nav > ul > li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var childUl = $(this).find('ul');
        $('#nav > ul > li > ul').each(function() {
            if (!childUl.is($(this))) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        if (childUl.length > 0 && childUl.css('display') == 'none') {
            e.preventDefault();
            childUl.toggle();
        }
    });
};
```

And the CSS:

```
body.active {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}

/* Menu */
@media screen and (max-width: 792px) {
    .aanmelden {
        display: none;
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .menuToggle {
        display: block;
    }

    #nav {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 110px;
        background: #e74a2b;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s; /* Safari */
        transition:max-height 0.3s;
    }

    #nav.active {
        max-height: calc(100% - 110px);
    }

    ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    ul li {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }

    ul li a:hover {
        color: #2c2c2c;
    }

    ul li a {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;    
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which browsers are you experiencing these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some messing around I found that this was the solution to my problem.

```
body.active {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

This is probably because a `position: fixed;` actually needs a fixed position.